# Sharing Beam State across different DoFns

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, beam

Is [Beam State](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) shared across different DoFns?

Lets say I have 2 DoFns:

- StatefulDoFn1: { myState.write(1)}
- StatefulDoFn2: { myState.read() ; do something ... output}

And then the pipeline in pseudocode:

pipline = readInput.........applyDoFn(StatefulDoFn1)......map{do something else}.......applyDoFn(StatefulDoFn2)

If I annotate myState identically in both StatefulDoFns - will what I write in StatefulDoFn1 be visible to StatefulDoFn2 , we implemented a pipeline with the assumption the answer is Yes ---- but it seems to be no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, state is local to each stateful `DoFn`, and it is also actually local to each key (and window, if you are using a window) inside that `DoFn`.

Comment: Thanks. I also believe that Beam State API is not meant to be used for such a case.